# Ajax post is not working in mvc razor

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view which contains two partial views. And in my controller I have a common action method for various http post methods here is the sample code:

```
 public ActionResult MyCommonMethode(modelclass object)
    {
 var BALObject = new BusinessLogic();
 -----------
 -----------
 return View("View", object);
    }

 [HttpPost, ActionName("MyCommonMethode"), Button(ButtonName = "searchbutton")]
    public ActionResult search(string searchstring)
    {
        ---------
         -------------
        return()
    }

 [HttpPost, ActionName("MyCommonMethode"), Button(ButtonName = "Save")]
    public ActionResult Edit(modelclass Object)
    {
        try
        {   -------------
             -----------
           -----------------
           return View("view", object);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             ----------------
            return RedirectToAction("error");
        }
    }
```

note that, the common method don't have any view, and  it is not a http get method.

now if I want to use an ajax call/post rather than a form submit, like shown

```
  $("#button").click(function () {

    //Set inserted values
    var name = $("#textvalue").val();

    // Call Create action method
    $.post('/myController/search', {
        "searchstring": name,
    },
        function () {
            alert("data is posted successfully");
            window.location.reload(true);

        });
});
```

so rather than loading the whole page I just want to refresh my partial view.
what are all the things I have to take care. pls help.

Comment: The success function receives the page HTML back as a parameter. Just take that and insert it into your page into a suitable container element.

Comment: Do you have a route map to bind myController/search to a valid action on the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace this:

```
function () {
        alert("data is posted successfully");
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
```

With:

```
function (data) {
       alert("data is posted successfully");
       $("#result").html(data);
    });
```

Where `#result` is the container of your partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the Action name as MyCommonMethode  using the attributes in Search Action method.
So you have to mention the UlR as /myController/MyCommonMethode as I mentioned in below code.

please Change the URL in the code

```
$("#button").click(function () {

//Set inserted values
var name = $("#textvalue").val();

// Call Create action method
$.post('/myController/MyCommonMethode', {
    "searchstring": name,
},
    function () {
        alert("data is posted successfully");
        window.location.reload(true); **or**  $("#result").html(data);

    });
});
```